# How to fix botched Outlook CSV data export 2013

Tags: database, csv, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-outlook-2013, export

When I exported contacts from outlook into a CSV file (to later upload it to Insightly database), it placed company names as part of the email address, it looks like this: Column named "E-mail" contains this text:

`graham@specair.com.au %SMTP %Graham Folkard (graham@specair.com.au)`

And field with a company name isn't exported at all. As a result Insightly does not import the contacts with no name (all the contacts listed as companies) and exports no email addresses as it sees the field as invalid, I guess).

There are 500 Outlook groups with contacts which were all exported manually, and now are unusable. Is there anything we can do to fix this issue? 
Perhaps a formula to edit the email column and split the text in it into two columns ("Company name" and "Email  address" ).

Any other ideas are also welcome as I need to fix this asap and upload the contacts to insightly to be on with our project management and I am just stuck here.